# jQuery Date Select Boxes plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, date

[The plugin.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DateSelectBoxes)

I have just implemented this and I noticed that if you select a month or a year it resets the day. This is particularly annoying as you always have to reset the day after choosing the year, and you would have to reset it twice if using the British format of day-month-year. This issue is also present in the demo provided.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: That is not the behavior I'm getting (Chrome, Firefox, and IE), nor is it the behavior on the author's demo site: http://www.nickabusey.com/jquery-date-select-boxes-plugin/. I would contact the developer or post some code so we can see why that might be happening.

Comment: it's not the behaviour you get from the demo, but the demo doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line right before the closing brace of the updateDays() function:

```
dayElem.val(selected);
```

What this will do is attempt to choose the chosen day if it is still available in the day select box after you change the month or year.